# Does the website loader has any impact on SEO?

Tags: seo, googlebot

I want to know wether the full screen loader-overlay (such I made [here](http://www.dock.cz/)) had any impact on SEO? Behind that white overlay is already rendered page using the php, but the content is obviously not visible without the javascript as the loader is being removed when all resources are ready...

Thanks for your answers and opinions!

Comment: No , Unless you decide to embed another page in loader itself.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, loaders do not have have a direct impact on SEO. Nowadays, search engines like Google are capable of executing some Javascript and find out about content created dynamically with it. It is always safe to have some text on your page to help search engines too.

However, loaders can have an indirect negative SEO impact if they are very slow or degrade the user experience significantly. When displaying your page (in search results for example), search engines will detect that users don't like it (they leave it early, they don't interact with it, etc...). As a consequence, your page would be displayed less often in search results.

Answer (score 1):

Don't believe there's any open Google response on this topic yet, however, I can tell you that Google will index apparently behind the scene content just fine. You'll even see SEO traffic from the content. If your site is fairly clean, You wouldn't worry about being flagged as having background content, as long as the content is accessible by user action (e.g. clicking).

But keep in mind most users don't spend a lot of time hunting, so to a user they might not find the content and bounce because they don't feel like they found the relevant information they were looking for. If you subscribe to the idea that Google and Bing use search query refinements as a search signal, this could potentially "harm" your SEO.

p.s. An alternative is to use crawlable AJAX or pushState() to have the individual parts of website render separately in their own region.